# RPI3 - Ubuntu 20.10 Unable to contact snap store

Tags: snap, raspberrypi, 20.10, arm64, snap-store

I’ve installed ubuntu 20.10 on my **RPi3-B (groovy-arm64)**.
It’s fully upgraded-to-day. when I tried to refresh packages(like lxd), it returned:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo snap refresh lxd
error: unable to contact snap store
```

The Internet connection is fine and other apps work perfectly.
snap can’t `refresh`, `find` and `install` any package!
I’m NOT behind any proxy.

`snap known serial` returns a valid `device-key`.

The ping and curl of the `api.snapcraft.io` is satisfying:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping api.snapcraft.io
PING api.snapcraft.io (91.189.92.38) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from api.snapcraft.io (91.189.92.38): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=151 ms
64 bytes from api.snapcraft.io (91.189.92.38): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=138 ms
64 bytes from api.snapcraft.io (91.189.92.38): icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=149 ms
64 bytes from api.snapcraft.io (91.189.92.38): icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=151 ms

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ curl https://api.snapcraft.io/
snapcraft.io store API service - Copyright 2018-2019 Canonical.
```

Here is more info:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ snap debug connectivity
Connectivity status:
*api.snapcraft.io: unreachable
error: 1 servers unreachable
```

Another output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ snap tasks 3
Status Spawn Ready Summary
Done today at 10:41 UTC today at 11:03 UTC Generate device key
Error today at 10:41 UTC today at 11:03 UTC Request device serial
…
Request device serial
2021-02-16T10:49:57Z ERROR cannot retrieve request-id for making a request for a serial: Post “https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/auth/request-id”: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2021-02-16T10:51:28Z ERROR cannot retrieve request-id for making a request for a serial: Post “https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/auth/request-id”: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2021-02-16T10:52:58Z ERROR cannot retrieve request-id for making a request for a serial: Post “https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/auth/request-id”: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2021-02-16T10:54:28Z ERROR cannot retrieve request-id for making a request for a serial: Post “https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/auth/request-id”: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2021-02-16T10:55:59Z ERROR cannot retrieve request-id for making a request for a serial: Post “https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/auth/request-id”: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2021-02-16T10:57:29Z ERROR cannot retrieve request-id for making a request for a serial: Post “https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/auth/request-id”: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2021-02-16T10:58:59Z ERROR cannot retrieve request-id for making a request for a serial: Post “https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/auth/request-id”: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2021-02-16T11:00:29Z ERROR cannot retrieve request-id for making a request for a serial: Post “https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/auth/request-id”: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2021-02-16T11:02:00Z ERROR cannot retrieve request-id for making a request for a serial: Post “https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/auth/request-id”: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2021-02-16T11:03:30Z ERROR cannot retrieve request-id for making a request for a serial: Post “https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/auth/request-id”: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

snap is working fine on my laptop **(focal-amd64)**.

anybody know where the problem is???

Thank you all

**UPDATE:**

After some days, now it's working; so weird!

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo snap refresh
All snaps up to date.
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be, at the time, snap services are down. Check the status at https://status.snapcraft.io/